# apache camel hibernate insert

Tags: json, hibernate, apache-camel

I have this camel route where json values from an url are inserted into my database.
code:

```
@Override
public void configure() throws Exception {
    //voor elke tabel een andere route want bij wijzigingen json formaat crashed enkel 1 routebuilder
    ObjectMapper objectMapper = new ObjectMapper();
    objectMapper.configure(DeserializationConfig.Feature.FAIL_ON_UNKNOWN_PROPERTIES, false);
    DataFormat jenkinsConfigFormat = new JacksonDataFormat(objectMapper, JenkinsConfiguration.class);

    jenkinsConfigurations = configurationService.listJenkinsConfigurations();
    logger.info("Starting routes for " + jenkinsConfigurations.size() + " jenkins configurations");

    for (JenkinsConfiguration configuration : jenkinsConfigurations) {
        from("timer://foo?fixedRate=true&period=120s&delay=20s")
                .to(configuration.getUrl() + "/api/json")
                .routeId(BUILD_ROUTE)
                .unmarshal(jenkinsConfigFormat)
                .enrich("direct:jenkinsconfig", new UseLatestAggregationStrategy())
                .split(simple("${body.builds}"))
                .choice()
                .when(buildNumberAlreadyExists())
                .otherwise()
                .to("hibernate:be.kdg.teamf.model.Build")
                .end();

        from("timer://foo?fixedRate=true&period=120s&delay=20s")
                .routeId(HEALTH_ROUTE)
                .to(configuration.getUrl() + "/api/json")
                .unmarshal(jenkinsConfigFormat)
                .enrich("direct:jenkinsconfig", new UseLatestAggregationStrategy())
                .split(simple("${body.healthReport}"))
                .choice()
                .when(healthReportAlreadyExists())
                .otherwise()
                .to("hibernate:be.kdg.teamf.model.HealthReport")
                .end();

        from("timer://foo?fixedRate=true&period=120s&delay=20s")
                .routeId(MODULE_ROUTE)
                .to(configuration.getUrl() + "/api/json")
                .unmarshal(jenkinsConfigFormat)
                .enrich("direct:jenkinsconfig", new UseLatestAggregationStrategy())
                .split(simple("${body.modules}"))
                .choice()
                .when(moduleAlreadyExists())
                .otherwise()
                .to("hibernate:be.kdg.teamf.model.Module")
                .end();

        List<Build> jenkinsBuilds = buildService.getBuildsJenkinsProject(configuration);
        DataFormat buildConfigFormat = new JacksonDataFormat(objectMapper, BuildDetail.class);
```

As you can see all jenkinsBuilds are loaded into a list:

```
List<Build> jenkinsBuilds = buildService.getBuildsJenkinsProject(configuration);
```

The first time when I run the program the list is empty.
The second time when I run the program the list is able to get the wanted values from my database.

My question is: How can I configure my routes so the list contains the same values like when i run it the second time?

Is it maybe possible to restart the whole Configure() method?

thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

The configure() method in a RouteBuilder is only invoked *once* when Camel startup (or if you add routes at runtime).

So maybe what you need is to have some logic that checks if there is any jenkins config data at all. And if not, then wait or what you need to do. And when there is data, you can in this logic create a new RouteBuilder instance of yours and add those routes to the running CamelContext - eg add routes at runtime.